# Firebase Analytics(Events or Conversion) for 2 row data

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a Flutter app. Normally, we can track events with one data. I want to track 2 data.

Normally with firebase we can track different events like:

- screen_view
- session_start
- first_open
- a
- b

What do I want?

- x | y together

How can I achieve this for my Flutter app in Firebase?

Must I use FireStore database? Is there way to do this with Firebase Analytics Events?

Comment: Firebase Analytics has nothing to do with the database products that are also offered by Firebase.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "store and track 2 data" and whether x and y are events or data points associated with events in your Flutter app with Firebase Analytics? More context will help provide a better answer. Thanks!

Comment: I edited thank you.

Comment: very simple... as I know we can create a new event in Firebase events but I know that we can create one row data. I need 2 row data, is it possible with firebase analytics?

Comment: You can log a custom event, and pass parameters there. Isn't this what you want, or can you write a code sample of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Could you show source or answer the question with code samples? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track events with multiple data or parameter by doing:

```
await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(
    name: "screen_view",
    parameters: {
        "x": "value_of_x",
        "y": "vallue_of_y",
    },
);
```

I used `screen_view` as sample event name. You can check the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=flutter) for more.

Comment: Yes, it seems that your answer is correct. Yesterday, I researched more and encountered with your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, it gives this error
https://i.ibb.co/GkyPz7c/Ekran-Resmi-2023-10-04-02-59-20.png

Comment: firebase_analytics: ^8.1.2
I don't want to change my analytics version. How can I do your solution with 8.1.2?

Comment: `FirebaseAnalytics().logEvent(
      name: 'screen_view',
      parameters: <String, dynamic>{
        "x": "value_of_x",
        "y": "vallue_of_y",
      },
    )`

Something like this should do

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/7463#issuecomment-986609171 I solved my problem with this.

Comment: Thats correct. Thats what i was referring to by `FirebaseAnalytics()`. The comment wasn't properly formatted. Would edit the solution to show.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid?hl=pt-br#dart) documentation?

All you got to do is set userId (using email or anything else you use) at your analytics implementation.

```
await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.setUserId(id: 'YOUR_ID');
```

As the documentation says:

> "After setting a user ID, all future events will be automatically
> tagged with this value, and you can access it by querying for the
> user_id value in BigQuery. Adding a user ID will not affect any events
> previously recorded by Google Analytics."

Comment: Please forget user id, this question was not for firebase-user id it was only an example.